# Why when I create a folder in Android Studio, I can't see it

Tags: android, android-studio

Why when I create some folder in Android Studio,  I can't see it afterwards? For example, I create a folder in the `res` directory, but then I can't see it. What could be the problem?

Comment: This problem also occurred with me sometime, but i restart my android studio and the folder are visible now.

Comment: is it created at all? if so, try to refresh the parent folder (or close/open it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try restarting Android Studio.
- Try changing your view from "Android" to "Project".

Comment: Thanks. I changed view Andoid to Project and now I see all of the folders.